# "sorry you are not allowed to access this page" when trying to pass variable in URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to plugin development and currently developing a custom CRUD plugin for a database.

I have created a admin page which shows all the database items in a table, and also i can add to this database. However when i try to pass a variable in the URL to edit a item from the database, i get the "sorry you are not allowed to access this page".

Currently it displays the database items in a table from a query then a for each loop, with a delete button in the row also.

```
   <?php

   foreach ($results as $results) {
     echo '<tr>';
     echo '<td>' .$results->id. '</td>';
     echo '<td>' .$results->email. '</td>';
     echo '<td><a class="button" href="' .home_url(). '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=member-management%2Fdelete_member.php?id=' .$results->id. '">Remove</a></td>';
     echo '</tr>';
    }

    ?>
```

The problem lies with the href here:

```
    href="' .home_url(). '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=member-management%2Fdelete_member.php?id=' .$results->id. '"
```

if i replace it with :

```
    href="' .home_url(). '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=member-management%2Fdelete_member.php'"
```

It works fine and goes to the page i want it to, does wordpress not allow variables passed in URL's?

Comment: Are you logged In using admin credentials in wordpress or not ?

Comment: @Bhavin yes i am, as a administrator!

Comment: @CallumSmith I guess the space between "?" and "page" in the first case is just a typo?. Have you checked php error log? maybe there is an error when deleting. Try commenting the delete code and see if error persists.

Comment: @Eduardo yeah it is, fixed now

Comment: @CallumSmith Have you checked php error log? maybe there is an error when deleting. Try commenting the delete code and see if error persists

Comment: `foreach ($results as $results)` is the same variable name.

Comment: @Eduardo i have checked and their is nothing of relevance to this issue in there, error still persists

Comment: @FelippeDuarte did a good point, did you check if id is being sent? or an error is sent? maybe that is the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your variables, replacing the second `$results` for `$result`. It works the way it is, but makes your code more readable.

And more important, fix the URL, replacing the second `?` with `&`

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' .$result->id. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' .$result->email. '</td>';
    echo '<td><a class="button" href="' .home_url(). '/wp-admin/admin.php?page=member-management%2Fdelete_member.php&id=' .$result->id. '">Remove</a></td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Worked a charm, the second ? Was the culprit!